# Banner Ad in Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio

```
     'public class AdFragment extends Fragment {

     @Nullable
     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup 
          container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 

    {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ad, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onActivityCreated(bundle);
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("some_string")
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    onDestroy();
       }
   }'
```

'

```
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/test_banner_ad_unit_id"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>'
```

Troubling to find the `addTestDevice()` and how to initialize `AdFragment` fragment? 
On running this code, there is either not showing any layout on the main screen as its showing no use of fragment in project, so where I should initialize the fragment in project.

Here is the java code as well as xml file. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try loading the add onCreateView of the AdFragment@Abhishek Kumar

Comment: Thanks it works..!!! @CrazyAndroid

Comment: Improve formatting and syntax of text